# Xamarin PCL-way to check password like password_verify

Tags: xamarin.forms, password-encryption

I am developing an App that checks on a web server if users exist but should support offline login. I am tempted to store the user's hash information locally to perform offline checks, so I return the `password_hash` generated via php on the server.

First of all - is that a secure enough approach? Is it possible to check the `password_hash` in a similar way as PHP's `password_verify` via PCL? Or should I consider creating a local salt/hash pair? I so, what is the suggested approach?

Answer (score 0):

I would think you generate hash in Xamarin and not sending the whole password to the server but in any case... PCL doesn't have that functionality but you can use DependancyService and implement that in platform specific code

For Andoid:

```
HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash("fgf");
```

For iOS

```
HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(stream);
```